# How to create notification popups that can automatically re-adjust not to overlap each other

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, popup

I have created a widget which looks like the following.
There are 3 panels which will track 3 different **items** and display their respective information.
Next to them will be a scrollviewer which outputs all the events that happens.

```
==============================================================
* This is  *          *          *|                          |
*    a     *          *          *| This is a scrollviewer   |
*  panel   *          *          *|                          |
==============================================================
```

I am trying to have a notification popup when an event occurs for the **item** and display for a few seconds before disappearing. E.g

```
==================
| Battery empty! |
|                |
|                |
==================
   ==============================================================
   * Item:1   * Item:2    * Item:3   *|Item 1 battery empty!     |
   *          *           *          *|                          |
   * Batt: 0  * Batt:55%  * Batt:80% *|                          |
   ===============================================================
```

However the width of the notification window is bigger than the panel. Hence if there are alerts for any other items, the notification popups will be overlapping each other.

```
============================
| Battery em|Battery full! |
|           |              |
|           |              |
============================
   ==============================================================
   * Item:1   * Item:2    * Item:3   *|Item 2 battery full!      |
   *          *           *          *|Item 1 battery empty!     |
   * Batt: 0  * Batt:100% * Batt:80% *|                          |
   ===============================================================
```

Is there a way for me to program the popups to avoid each other and automatically readjust themselves to the side? And if it is too difficult is there any other method such using window as a popup?

```
================   ===============  ===============
| Battery empty |  |Battery full!|  | Battery empty |
|               |  |             |  |               |
|               |  |             |  |               |
=================  ===============  =================
       ==============================================================
       * Item:1   * Item:2    * Item:3   *|Blah blah                 |
       *          *           *          *|.....                     |
       * Batt: 0  * Batt:100% * Batt: 0  *|.....                     |
       ===============================================================
```

*The panels are usercontrols stored in an itemcontrol of the main window.

Comment: added more accurate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show Popups adjacent to each other, we can set Placement to Relative, and set HorizontalOffset property of subsequent Popups to increase by 200 (width of popup).

For eg; 1st Popup will have HorizontalOffset to 0, 2nd to 200, 3rd to 400 and so on.

```
<Popup x:Name="Popup1" PlacementTarget="{Binding MyCanvas}" IsOpen="False" Placement="Relative">
    <Grid Background="Red" Width="200" Height="200"></Grid>
</Popup>

<Popup x:Name="Popup2" PlacementTarget="{Binding MyCanvas}" IsOpen="False" Placement="Relative" HorizontalOffset="200">
    <Grid Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="200"></Grid>
</Popup>

<Popup x:Name="Popup3" PlacementTarget="{Binding MyCanvas}" IsOpen="False" Placement="Relative" HorizontalOffset="400">
    <Grid Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="200"></Grid>
</Popup>
```

This will place Popups adjacent to each other like shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am now busy with a different project, but I'll be testing out your implementation in a few weeks time

Comment: People are not fools to answer your questions. When you are posting a question, you have to check the answer and reply back properly.

Comment: Yes I am saying I cannot know if your suggestion is the answer without trying it out. Once I go back to testing your suggestion, and if it works, then I will be able to know if I can mark your reply as the answer. I cannot simply mark someone's reply as the answer without checking properly right? But due to time constrains by my boss, I cannot work on this immediately. It will be done in due time, and if it works, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Tested. Imo there is no point in binding popups to the canvas since you can bind it to the window grid and set the offset as well. 

But I learnt that the canvas can be made transparent and controls can fall through application below.  Used a stackpanel inside the canvas. Changed from popups to Listview so that I can put them in the stackpanel. 
Window and Canvas size must be set to larger than the intended application size. 
Background = Transparent, AllowsTransparency = true;